# Why does ZXing give me black screen when do activity before captureAcitivity

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing

I use *ZXing* to scan barcode but I have a problem that:
If I make load screen and use handler to start `CaptureActivity` It's work very fine.

But If I have other activity such as a MainMenu Activity. after I start `CaptureActivity` through the button on mainmenu the barcode scaner give me a black screen like a shut down camera or sth.

please help.
Thanks you very much in advance.

UPDATE: on the 4 corners of screen will see light from camera. if you use your hand close the camera 4 corners will became black. but just a few space on corners only.

UPDATE2: I found that if i change orientation physically in the activity before start CaptureActivity the app work fine. It weird but true. but I need to do this every time i use app? Please help. Thanks you very much.

Comment: You aren't providing any specific detail about your app, which is where the error is.. this is nothing to do with zxing per se.

Comment: There not error in log. but the problem is black screen on camera.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the application permission to use the camera otherwise the screen will be black.
To do this, open the android manifest file and add the camera option.

Comment: Of course, I did give an application permission to use camera. But It doesn't matter right now, This question has been asked from Jan 2012. and now I'm move to working on iOS application development, thanks for reply anyway.